# js regex to wrap numbers and variables in string in span tags

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a string like so:

```
${1}${2}${3}${4}%9${5}00
```

And I'm wanting to wrap all the numbers and vars in span tags But the issue is there can be an unlimited number of **"${1}"** variables in this string.

The current regex I'm using is

```
str.replace(/([0-9\/\+\(\)\%\-\*v]{1})/g, '<span>$1</span>')
```

But the problem with this regex is it wraps the $, { and } in a separate span tag. I'm wanting to wrap the **"${1}"** in its own span tag.

How would I do this and if possible can you explain the regex.

Thanks

---

Working example:

```
et str = '${1}${2}${3}${4}%9${5}00';

let copy = str.replace(/(\$\{\d+\}|[\d/+()%*v-])/g, '<span>$1</span>');

console.log('Copy: ', copy)
```

Comment: Could you add the expected output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = '${1}${2}${3}${4}%9${5}00';

str = str.replace(/\$\{\d+\}|[\d/+()%*v-]/g, '<span>$&</span>');

console.log(str);
```

The regex will match either of two alternatives separated by `|`.

**First**, it will try to match a "variable" using `\${\d+}` then it will try to match a number or symbol using `[\d\/+()%*v-]`.

Whatever is matched is then referenced using `$&` (the full match) in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC,

How about a simple regex with

```
str.replace(/(\$\{\d\})/g, '<span>$1</span>')
```

The output is:

```
'<span>${1}</span><span>${2}</span><span>${3}</span><span>${4}</span>%9<span>${5}</span>00'
```

It matches `${<digit>}`, if you want to match more digits, for examples `${11}` or `${123}`, you can simply put `\d+` in place of `\d`.

Here is the updated version matching the special characters as well with different capture groups.

```js
const str = "${1}${2}${3}${4}%9${5}00"
const out = str.replace(/(\$\{\d+\}|\%|\d)/g, '<span>$1</span>')
console.log(out)
```

Comment: This one wont work also. Because all the numbers and symbols like “9” and ”%”. They also need to be wrapped in a span tag

Comment: @TheMan68 I'll get back to you when I'm at the computer

Comment: @TheMan68 Here, I updated the snippet!